# Excel: Matching a string from a list of strings

Tags: excel

I have two lists:

list 1:

```
gnat
dog
cat
house
dog
```

list 2:

```
dog
mouse
flat
cat
cat
```

I want to check if any of the words in list 2 are in list 1, regardless of where the word exists in the list, so in the end, I should get something like this:

```
gnat   dog   Yes
dog    mouse No
cat    flat  No
house  cat   Yes
dog    cat   Yes
```

Does anyone know how I can do this? I've tried the following but have had no luck:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A:A,B1)), "Yes", "No")
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A:A,B:1)),"Yes", "No")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **C1**:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,B1)=0,"No","Yes")
```

[image]

and copy down.

For *dog*, you will get "Yes" no matter how many *dog*s there are in column **A**.

Comment: Nice Gary!  I think I am coming down with a case of Craner-itis!  I immediately started thinking of a sumproduct method!  You have the better approach!

Comment: @ForwardEd  I must agree with you..............I also considered *SUMPRODUCT()* first